# Algorithm to consume monthly cost of energy

Tags: python

this runs fine but doesn't produce the results i need. my guess is i'm missing something simple in the math. that's where the issue is i'm sure.

```
bill = 0
months = 12
kwhour = .06
kwhour2 = .08

for months in range(1, months+1):

    month_start = int(input('month ' + str(months) + ' starting reading: '))
    month_end = int(input('month ' + str(months) + ' ending reading: '))

    if month_end <= 1000:
        output1 = month_end * kwhour
        output1 += 1
    else:
        output2 = month_end * kwhour2
        output2 += 1

        bill = output1 + output2

print('Your yearly bill is: ', bill)

if bill < 500:
    print('Thanks for saving so much energy')
```

Comment: What are the results you need?

Comment: Also, should `kwhour2` be the rate for *all kWh used if the total is more than 1000*, or just for the portion over 1000kWh?

Comment: `for months in range(1, months+1)` does a strange thing: it redefines `months` during iteration. Try something like `for duration in range(1, months + 1)` and see where you need what in your formulas.

Comment: @9000 that's true, but it doesn't really matter - `months` isn't used after the loop (and will be back to `12` anyway).

Comment: You need to give more context so we can help you.

Comment: my apologies, this is my first post here and wan't sure how much i needed to explain. i will do better next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I understood, you are reading values from `energy meter (counter)` at the end of every month. You should calculate the difference between what u'r reading at the end and beginning of every month. THat's what u consumed in that month. Then, multiply what u consumed with the right hourly factor kwhour/kwhour2 and sum everytime. I still didn't understand whay he's adding one everytime (but he could explain).
You don't need `bill += output1 + output2` u r going to add things that u don't need to add, that's why u r adding `if condition`.

`'bill= output1+output2'` doesn't solve the issue. Imagine if u loop and got into case `<=1000` (Update output1), next time u got into case `>1000`  (Update output2). Third time, if u got into any case (let's say to update 'output1'), u'r going to add an outdated value 'output2' to bill. you should add output1/2 separately in every block (`bill+=output1 / bill+=output2` )

```
   bill = 0
   months = 12
   kwhour = .06
   kwhour2 = .08
   output1=0
   output2=0

  for m in range(1, months+1):

      month_start = int(input('month ' + str(m) + ' starting reading: '))
      month_end = int(input('month ' + str(m) + ' ending reading: '))

         if (month_end-month_start) <= 1000:
              output1 = (month_end-month_start) * kwhour
              #output1 += 1
              bill+=output1
         else:
              output2 = (month_end-month_start) * kwhour2
              #output2 += 1
              bill+=output2

         #bill += output1 + output2 You don't need this, u gonna re-adding things 

 print('Your yearly bill is: ', bill)

 if bill < 500:
     print('Thanks for saving so much energy')
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to intialize the variable **output1 and output2 to zero**,then total bill addition should be outside the **if and else** loop.  You can rewrite like this:

```
   bill = 0
   months = 12
   kwhour = .06
   kwhour2 = .08
   output1=0
   output2=0

  for months in range(1, months+1):

      month_start = int(input('month ' + str(months) + ' starting reading: '))
      month_end = int(input('month ' + str(months) + ' ending reading: '))

         if month_end <= 1000:
              output1 = month_end * kwhour
              output1 += 1
         else:
              output2 = month_end * kwhour2
              output2 += 1

         bill += output1 + output2

 print('Your yearly bill is: ', bill)

 if bill < 500:
     print('Thanks for saving so much energy')
```

I got following output:

```
     ('Your yearly bill is: ', 47.03999999999999)
     Thanks for saving so much energy
```

Comment: not sure if it's my python or what, but my result still came up 0 for every result no matter what the input was. thats was the original issue i was having.

Comment: But I was able to get the output. Can you refer my code and try

Comment: i used your code and using 0 as a start and 100 as an end for each of the 12 months, the result should have been 72.00, but i still got a 0. i do appreciate the help tho.

Comment: I got following output for 0 and 100:                                      ('Your yearly bill is: ', 84.0)
Thanks for saving so much energy  . Please be sure with the indentation. Indentation will make major role in python .

Comment: that might be what the problem was. again, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You reassign bill at every loop

`bill = output1 + output2`

try to add instead

`bill += output1 + output2`

Also you don't really need output1 and output2, add directly to bill instead

```
if month_end <= 1000:
    bill += month_end * kwhour
    bill += 1 # I dont see why you add 1 here
else:
    bill += month_end * kwhour2
    bill += 1
```

Comment: Update the second one to be: 'bill += month_end * kwhour2', otherwise, it would be confusing for him.

Comment: regarding the +1... was just shooting for the stars in hopes something would work. it got late and i just started throwing things in. but i do appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `for months` do `for month` because months is already declared variable. u shouldn't iterate with it. second, update bill as `bill=bill+output1+output2`